# Обработчик на php для формы html + jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, форма

Не получается заставить работать небольшой скрипт ajax.php, который:

1. Должен получать данные из html формы посредством AJAX запроса;
2. Формировать тело письма;
3. Отправлять письмо с полученными данными на e-mail админу.

Форму на html организовал таким образом:

```html
<form name="form1" class="form1">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Имя">
    <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон">
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="E-mail">
    <input type="hidden" id="tema" value="Заявка на получение прайса">      
</form>
<form id="open_tab" target="_blank" action="files/price.docx"></form>
<div class="divButt"><a href="" class="butt SendPr1">Получить прайс</a></div>
```

Данную форму обрабатывает следующий JS код:

```js
$('a.SendPr1').click(function() {
    var name = $('input#name').val();
    var phone = $('input#phone').val();
    var email = $('input#email').val();
    var tema = $('input#tema').val();
    var page = $('input#page').val();
    var otUrl = $('input#otUrl').val();
    var nfilter = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9 \-]+$/;
    var tfilter = /^[0-9-\ \(\)\+]+$/;
    var emailfilter = /^([a-z0-9_\-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_\-]+@([a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z]{2,4}$/i;

    g = 0;

    if (!tfilter.test(phone)) {
        $('input#phone').css('color', 'red');
        $('input#phone').css('border-color', 'red');
        g = 1;
    } else {
        $('input#phone').css('color', '#1f1f1f');
        $('input#phone').css('border-color', '#ffffff');
    }

    if (!nfilter.test(name)) {
        $('input#name').css('color', 'red');
    } else {
        $('input#name').css('color', '#1f1f1f');
    }

    if (!emailfilter.test(email)) {
        $('input#email').css('color', 'red');
        $('input#email').css('border-color', 'red');
        g = 1;
    } else {
        $('input#email').css('color', '#1f1f1f');
        $('input#email').css('border-color', '#ffffff');
    }

    if (name.length == 0) g = 1;
    if (phone.length == 0) g = 1;
    if (email.length == 0) g = 1;

    if (g == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: "tel=" + phone + "&name=" + name + "&mail=" + email + "&tema=" + tema + "&page=" + page + "&oturl=" + otUrl,
            success: function(html) {
                if (html == 'error') {
                    alert('Извините, во время отправки сообщения произошла ошибка.\n\nОбратитесь по телефону и мы с удовольствием проконсультируем вас.');
                } else {
                    alertt('Спасибо, что выбрали нас!', 'В ближайшее время Вам позвонит наш специалист.');
                    showPopup(3);
                    document.form1.reset();
                    $("#open_tab").submit();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

У меня есть примерное содержание ajax.php, (http://lexest.vshatre.by/ajax.txt), но скрипт, естественно, не работает.

КОНКРЕТИЗИРУЮЩИЙ ВОПРОС:
**Как именно распарсить эту строку**:

```
data: "tel="+phone+"&name="+name+"&mail="+email+"&tema="+tema
```

посылаемую через ajax, и **получить в ajax.php указанные пользователем данные**, чтобы в дальнейшем сформировать из них письмо и отправить e-mail админу?

Comment: Что именно вас смущает? Собственно отправка на e-mail, или же обработка формы, отправляемой AJAXом? Если таки AJAX, то может эта статья поможет: http://codeproject.com/Tips/1065669/How-To-Build-Web-Site-With-AJAX-HTMLplusCSSplusJSp

Comment: Я не знаю, как именно в ajax.php принять данные посылаемые с помощью AJAX `data: "tel="+phone+"&name="+name+"&mail="+email+"&tema="+tema+"&page="+page+"&oturl="+otUrl` чтобы иметь возможность ими оперировать для дальнейшего отправления письма.

Comment: Смотрите документацию по php, или наймите фрилансера

Comment: @АндрейДушков В `php` есть спец. переменные для работы с такими данными [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.get.php), [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.post.php), [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.request.php). [Пример](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php). Что касается отправки писем можно использовать нативную функцию [mail](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php), или спользовать одну из множества библиотек, лично я предпочитаю  [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону PHPMailer и отправки писем через PHPMailer через smtp.

https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

http://progger.ru/2009/07/phpmailer-otpravka-pisem-cherez-smtp/

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?